# Make file compiling of benchmarking application

Tags: c

I am working on a benchmark application of "San Diego Vision benchmarks suite" and the source code is in c language and it has make file. through terminal in Ubuntu I tried to run "gmake c-run" command, it should run but it gives following error. I search this website with similar errors but it didn't help me.  it also state that undefined reference to ceil and floor, but math library is attach and also lm flag is used, so it should not display this warning.

```
/tmp/ccTbPnbf.o: In function 'ffConv2_dY':  
ffConv2_dY.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to 'ceil'  
ffConv2_dY.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to 'ceil'  
/tmp/ccdUhc55.o: In function 'ffiConv2':  
ffiConv2.c:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to 'ceil'  
ffiConv2.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to 'ceil'  
/tmp/ccZYap2H.o: In function 'fiConv2':  
fiConv2.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to 'ceil'  
/tmp/ccZYap2H.o:fiConv2.c:(.text+0x81): more undefined references to 'ceil' follow  
/tmp/ccrkxxLX.o: In function 'imageResize':  
imageResize.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to 'floor'  
imageResize.c:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to 'floor'  
/tmp/ccxvX9jf.o: In function 'randnWrapper':  
randnWrapper.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to 'log'  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
gmake: *** [compile] Error 1
```

Can someone please guide me or give me a hint so that I can figure out this issue.

Comment: You need to link against the math library. If using `gcc` add `-lm` to the compiler flags

Comment: @MortenJensen Shouldn't this be done when he invokes make? I think he is missing some dependencies. @ zeeshan Isn't there some kind of compilation aid provided in the source tree, maybe read the REAMDE for further advice.

Comment: @maxik yes I agree that the compiler flags should be in the Makefile. Usually there is a README file or an INSTALLING file to tell what must be present on the system.

Comment: thanxk you maxik and Morten jensen for your comments.  -lm is used to compiler flags already but i also agree to maxik that some dependencies are missed but I am unable to figure out this issue. there is read file and some help but according to them it should run smoothly. but it gives above mention error.

Comment: @zeeshankhan Without further information I may not help you with that, sorry. You really should check all dependencies. Good Luck.

Comment: @maxik thanx alot maxik. I will check dependencies and i hope i will figure it out. .have a nice time